# Get number of elements in a Vector

Tags: java, vector, enumeration

I have this code.

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Enumeration;

/*Part Of My Private Code*/

private Vector clietns = new Vector();
private DataOutputStream remoteOut;

/*Part Of My Private Code*/

clients.addElement(remoteOut);

/*Part Of My Private Code*/

Enumeration e = clients.elements();
System.out.println(e + "");
```

This returns the hex code of Enumeration e.
How could I obtain the exact number of elements (in integer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the method `size()` from `Vector`. `Enumeration` doesn't give you that method, since it can be used to enumerate elements even if the full number isn't known.

Next time you're wondering a thing like this, please go see the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) first.

As a last tip, `Vector` and `Enumeration` are considered outdated. You should use `ArrayList` and `Iterator` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Vector.size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#size()) method. It will tell you the number of elements in the vector.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot get the number of items from an Enumeration.

Note that the only two methods of this interface are:

```
hasMoreElements()
E   nextElement()
```

So it is not intended to behave as a collection that usually knows the number of items inside them.

You should use vector `size()` method instead that returns an integer.

Comment: O.K. Enumerations could be used to loop through the elemets of a vector. But not actually to get the elemets in a Vector....

Answer (score 0):

Questions like this are best to do a little research before posting.

Take a look at the API page for Java and you'll find what you're looking for. *(Hint, the function is going to return an int)*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html